# Showing the correction of index image in scrollview when change orientation

Tags: ios, scrollview

My app supports both orientation modes (Landscape and Portrait). 
I have 4 images in scrollView and my problem is when I stand as portrait at image index 1 after I change to Landscape mode it always show the image at index 0. So I want to solve this
problem by show the image that correspond with index from Land <-> Port, please give the idea or some codes.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this method for my paging `UIScrollView`...

```
// Delegate method
-(void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    // Store current position (the offset by half the view is to be more accurate when paging)
    curPos = (scrollView.contentOffset.x + scrollView.bounds.size.width/2) / scrollView.bounds.size.width;

}

-(void) viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    // Scroll back to the current item
    scroll.contentOffset = CGPointMake(curPos * scroll.bounds.size.width, 0);

}
```

Then all you need is an `int curPos` in your class header...

Comment: It can catch the current position, but after I implement method viewWillLayoutSubviews I can not scroll. WHy?